# Examining Output of raw files C++

Tags: c++, image, binary

Hi I am reading in a binary file formatted in hex. It is an image file below is a short example of the first few lines of code using hd ... |more command on linux. The image is a binary graphic so the only pixel colours are either black or white. It is a 1024 by 1024 image however the size comes out to be 2097152 bytes

**00000000**  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|

**000dfbf0**  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 ff 00 ff 00  |................|

**000dfc00**  ff 00 ff 00 ff 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|

**000dfc10**  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|

This is the code I am using to read it in found in another thread on SO

```
ifstream file (argv[1], ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);
ifstream::pos_type fileSize;
char* fileContents;
if(file.is_open())
{
    fileSize = file.tellg();
    fileContents = new char[fileSize];
    file.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    if(!file.read(fileContents, fileSize))
    {
        cout << "fail to read" << endl;
    }
 file.close();
 cout << fileSize << endl;
```

The code works however when I run this for loop

```
for (i=0; i<2097152; i++)
 printf("%hd",fileContents[i]);
```

The only thing printed out are zeros and no 1s. Why is this are my parameters in printf not correctly specifying the pixel size. I know for a fact that there are 1's in the image representing the white areas. Also how do i figure out how many bytes represent a pixel in this image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `printf()` is wrong.  `%hd` means `short`, while `fileContents[i]` is a `char`; on all modern systems I'm familiar with, this is a size mismatch.  Use an array of `short` instead, since you have twice as many bytes as pixels.

Also, stop using `printf()` and use `std::cout`, avoiding all type mismatch problems.

Comment: how will cout know to access 2 bytes at a time and change those into decimal to represent a pixel value of 1 or 0

Comment: @user1084113:  `cout` will know because you will pass it a `short`, not a `char`.  `format()` takes your word for the size of the value passed, and you were lying to it.

Answer (score 0):

Since 2097152/1024 is exactly 2048 which is in turn 2*1024, I would assume each pixel is 2 bytes.

The other problem is probably in the `printf`. I'm not sure what `%hd` is, I would use `%02x` myself and cast the data to `int`.